# Do I need to create seperate model for each table in database

Tags: php, laravel

My question is more theoritical, as I am not quite sure if it is a better way to create a model in Laravel for each table on database, if yes, what would be the benefition of it? 
I am using Laravel 4 Eloquent for the ORM.
Thanks

Comment: The basic answer is yes, you should have a model for each table. But the long answer is "it depends".

Comment: I was more interested on the longer answer actually, when not?

Comment: When not depends on whether you're modelling domain objects or merely database objects

Comment: I meant database objects

Comment: If you're modelling database objects, then you need a model for every database table that you need to access, whether directly or via a relation, though you don't necessarily need models for (many-to-many x-reference tables)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic answer is yes, you should have a model for each table.

But the long answer is "it depends". As for what "depends" is, it is something that comes with experience and also your design criteria. There is no 100% right answer that can be used everytime.

As a *principle* if you plan on accessing data from tables using Eloquent, then you generally need one eloquent model per table, so you can access the table using Eloquent functions.

As a *principle* you dont need a model if you never use Eloquent to access the data. i.e. perhaps you have a table that you only use the query builder on.

Comment: Additionally, a pivot table would traditionally not require a model.